# HOw to fix bundler issue: You have already activated mysql 2.7, but your Gemfile requires mysql 2.8.1. Consider using bundle exec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

After I deployed my rails 2.2.2 application to production I am getting this error:
"You have already activated mysql 2.7, but your Gemfile requires mysql 2.8.1. Consider using bundle exec"

Gemfile has the correct information. How do I fix this issue?

**Update**
I would like to use `gem 'mysql', '2.8.1'` but somehow didn't work for me. Here is what I have in server gem list:

```
....
libxml-ruby (1.1.3)
memcache-client (1.6.3)
mysql (2.7)
net-scp (1.0.2)
net-sftp (2.0.2)
net-ssh (2.0.11)
....
```

Here is how my Gemfile look like:

```
require 'rubygems'
source 'http://rubygems.org'
source 'http://gemcutter.org'
source 'http://gems.github.com'
gem 'rails', '2.2.2'
gem 'hpricot', '0.6.0'
gem "composite_primary_keys", '2.2.0'
gem 'javan-whenever', '0.3.7'
gem 'mysql', '2.7' ** earlier I was trying with 2.8.1 then used 2.7 and it worked**
gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter', '1.1.9'
gem 'ruby-oci8', '1.0.3'
gem 'crypto', '0.0.3'
gem 'rack', '1.0.0'
gem 'mechanize', '1.0.0'

group :test do
  gem 'mocha', '0.9.5'
  gem 'rspec',             '1.3.1', :require => 'spec'
  gem 'rspec-rails',       '1.3.3'
end

group :cruise do
  gem 'metric_fu', '1.5.1'
end
```

Comment: When I encountered this problem, it was almost always because I had some require 'mysql' in my code. Do you have such statements in your app?

Comment: @mosch I don't have require 'mysql' anywhere in the code, except the fact that, it is in mysql-2.8.1/test/test_mysql.rb. So not sure this is the error, but as soon as I changed my Gemfile to use mysql 2.7 it worked. mysql-2.7 doesn't have test folder, so there is no require 'mysql'

Comment: I see, I assumed you need mysql 2.8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to explicitly set mysql version in Gemfile: `gem "mysql", "2.7"`

Comment: this is what really worked for me. but ideally I should be able to use mysql 2.8.1

Comment: I am glad to help you. Let me share some expirience with you: I had many projects I working on, and there are always gem dependency appears :) so my colegues and I started to explicitly set gem versions in Gemfiles. For example for rails 3.0.5 we use mysql2 2.0.6, because there are troubles with later versions. So just explicitly set working version of your favourite gems and everyting will be fine )

Comment: this is why it seems pretty annoying. I explicitly gave gem "mysql", '2.8.1' in Gemfile and even then it gave me this error. It should have worked, as I always use exact version in Gemfile

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to uninstall the `2.7` version and then install the `2.8` one? The reason I am asking is I've faced exactly the same error with another gem... Just yesterday in fact. I fixed this simply with these:

```
gem uninstall mysql -v 2.7
gem install mysql -v 2.8.1
```

I believe if you run the first command and then running `bundle install`, you will get the correct one. Or you may go back and change the version string in your `Gemfile` to the one you really want.

Comment: I thought about it, but this is option will not work for me, as there are few other applications working on the server that are not using bundler and will fail if I uninstall mysql 2.7

Comment: Are you using rvm to manage your gemests/ruby versions? If not you should look into it--you can easily segregate projects that use different gemsets or even different versions of ruby.

Comment: yep good idea, we are trying to move projects to rvm and bundler, but this process will take some time, but definately that's the goal.

Comment: I ended up spending a lot of time at home on weekends "practicing" setting up rvm and creating projects that use it. After a few tries I've become fairly competent in setting it up. It's definitely worth the pain...